# elasticsearch python regex query

Tags: python, regex, elasticsearch

I want to execute queries like "my * is" which should yield results like "my name is", "my car is" etc.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
client = Elasticsearch([
    {'host': 'localhost', 'port':9200}
    ])
s = Search(using=client, index="index_name") \
    .query('regexp', title="my * is")
response = s.execute()
```

But I am getting empty response.

Comment: I guess you may try with `my [^ ]* is`.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to Wikto Stribizew for the correct answer in the comments.
this thing worked for me.

```
my [^ ]* is
```

It is strange that *,? etc as such aren't accepted because they are actually referring to some other things as mentioned in [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)

Thanks,